# Compose is recompose whole screen when updating text in edit text

Tags: android, firebase, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using compose in my android app and I uses the approach of data class to put all the states on it and update the data class by using copy function and update what I want to update in the data class but the problem is that when I observed the layout inspector I found that the whole scree recomposed when I update the text in the edit text or generally it recomposes when I update the data class whatever what I updated on it so I need help to minimize the number of unnecessary recompose or recompose what I update only and in the same time organize my code and manage state in a good manner what to do?

Screen UI

```
@Composable
fun EmailPasswordScreen(
    viewModel: EmailPasswordRegisterViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    context: Context = LocalContext.current
) {
    val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
    EmailPasswordScreenContent(
        uiState = uiState,
        onEmailChanged = viewModel::onEmailChanged,
        onPasswordChanged = viewModel::onPasswordChanged,
        onRegisterClicked = viewModel::onRegisterClicked,
        onLoginClicked = viewModel::onLoginClicked
    )
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = uiState.successMsg){
        if(uiState.successMsg.isNotEmpty())
            Toast.makeText(context, uiState.successMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = uiState.errorMsg){
        if(uiState.errorMsg.isNotEmpty())
            Toast.makeText(context, uiState.errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}

@Composable
fun EmailPasswordScreenContent(
    uiState: EmailPasswordUIState,
    onEmailChanged: (String) -> Unit,
    onPasswordChanged: (String) -> Unit,
    onRegisterClicked: () -> Unit,
    onLoginClicked: () -> Unit
) {
    Column(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(24.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        InputSection(
            email = uiState.email,
            password = uiState.password,
            errors = uiState.errors,
            onEmailChanged = onEmailChanged,
            onPasswordChanged = onPasswordChanged
        )
        VerticalSpacer32()
        ActionSection(
            onRegisterClicked = onRegisterClicked,
            isRegisterLoading = uiState.isRegisterLoading,
            onLoginClicked = onLoginClicked,
            isLoginLoading = uiState.isLoginLoading
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun InputSection(
    email: String,
    onEmailChanged: (String) -> Unit,
    password: String,
    onPasswordChanged: (String) -> Unit,
    errors: List<PossibleFormErrors>
) {
    Column {
        TextField(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            value = email,
            onValueChange = onEmailChanged,
            isError = errors.contains(PossibleFormErrors.EMAIL_INVALID),
            label = { Text(text = stringResource(R.string.e_mail)) },
            supportingText = {
                if (errors.contains(PossibleFormErrors.EMAIL_INVALID)) {
                    Text(
                        text = stringResource(R.string.invalid_email_address),
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error
                    )
                }
            }
        )
        VerticalSpacer16()
        TextField(
            value = password,
            onValueChange = onPasswordChanged,
            label = { Text(text = stringResource(R.string.password)) },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            isError = errors.contains(PossibleFormErrors.PASSWORD_INVALID),
            supportingText = {
                if (errors.contains(PossibleFormErrors.PASSWORD_INVALID)) {
                    Text(
                        text = stringResource(R.string.invalid_password),
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error
                    )
                }
            }
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun ActionSection(
    onRegisterClicked: () -> Unit,
    isRegisterLoading: Boolean,
    onLoginClicked: () -> Unit,
    isLoginLoading: Boolean
) {
    Button(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(200.dp)
            .height(52.dp)
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)),
        onClick = onRegisterClicked,
        enabled = !isRegisterLoading
    ) {
        if (isRegisterLoading) {
            CircularProgressIndicator(color = Color.White)
        } else {
            Text(
                text = stringResource(R.string.register),
                fontFamily = SfDisplay,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                fontSize = 16.sp,
            )
        }
    }
    VerticalSpacer28()
    Button(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(200.dp)
            .height(52.dp)
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)),
        onClick = onLoginClicked,
        enabled = !isLoginLoading
    ) {
        if (isLoginLoading) {
            CircularProgressIndicator(color = Color.White)
        } else {
            Text(
                text = stringResource(R.string.login),
                fontFamily = SfDisplay,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                fontSize = 16.sp,
            )
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showSystemUi = true)
@Composable
fun EmailPasswordScreenPreview() {
    EmailPasswordScreen()
}
```

viewmodel

```
package com.mahmoudibrahem.firebaseplayground.ui.screens.auth.email_password

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import com.mahmoudibrahem.firebaseplayground.repository.auth_repository.AuthRepository
import com.mahmoudibrahem.firebaseplayground.util.PossibleFormErrors
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.asStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.update
import javax.inject.Inject

@HiltViewModel
class EmailPasswordRegisterViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val authRepository: AuthRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(EmailPasswordUIState())
    val uiState = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    fun onEmailChanged(newValue: String) {
        _uiState.update { it.copy(email = newValue) }
    }

    fun onPasswordChanged(newValue: String) {
        _uiState.update { it.copy(password = newValue) }
    }

    fun onRegisterClicked() {
        isFormValid()
        if (_uiState.value.errors.isEmpty()) {
            _uiState.update { it.copy(errorMsg = "", successMsg = "", isRegisterLoading = true) }
            authRepository.registerEmailPassword(
                email = _uiState.value.email,
                password = _uiState.value.password
            ).addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                _uiState.update {
                    it.copy(
                        successMsg = "Success UID = ${result.user?.uid}",
                        isRegisterLoading = false
                    )
                }
            }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                _uiState.update {
                    it.copy(
                        errorMsg = exception.message.toString(),
                        isRegisterLoading = false
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun onLoginClicked() {
        isFormValid()
        if (_uiState.value.errors.isEmpty()) {
            _uiState.update { it.copy(errorMsg = "", successMsg = "", isLoginLoading = true) }
            authRepository.loginEmailPassword(
                email = _uiState.value.email,
                password = _uiState.value.password
            ).addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                _uiState.update {
                    it.copy(
                        successMsg = "Success UID = ${result.user?.uid}",
                        isLoginLoading = false
                    )
                }
            }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                _uiState.update {
                    it.copy(
                        errorMsg = exception.message.toString(),
                        isLoginLoading = false
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun isFormValid() {
        _uiState.value.errors.clear()
        val email = _uiState.value.email
        val password = _uiState.value.password
        if (!email.matches(Regex("^[\\w-.]+@([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]{2,4}\$")) || email.isEmpty())
            _uiState.value.errors.add(PossibleFormErrors.EMAIL_INVALID)
        if (password.length < 8)
            _uiState.value.errors.add(PossibleFormErrors.PASSWORD_INVALID)
    }

}
```

Data class

```
@Immutable
data class EmailPasswordUIState(
    val email: String = "",
    val password: String = "",
    val isLoginLoading: Boolean = false,
    val isRegisterLoading: Boolean = false,
    val errors: SnapshotStateList<PossibleFormErrors> = mutableStateListOf(),
    val successMsg: String = "",
    val errorMsg: String = ""
)
```

Any one can help?

I expect to make compose recompose only what I updated